# Custom allow this app to use location popup iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, location

I have an agreement view at the very first of my app.  I want to have the user check a custom made box saying that the app can use their location, instead of the normal Alert view that comes up.  Can I override this?

Comment: You can customize the message of the system alert but you can't change the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to have the user give permission through the system alert view.